# Mac executable runs on a terminal but not in an app

Tags: java, bash, macos, shell, deployment

I created a mac app based on a fat jar file and a shell executable that launches it. When I launched the executable by double-clicking it on a terminal, it launched the app successfully. So, I put the executable (same name as the app) in the MacOs folder in the Contents folder. However, when I clicked the .app folder, the app did not launch. As I understand, clicking an app should launch the executable file in the MacOs folder, but instead, my mac threw a 'the app cannot be opened' message.

What could be the problem? Also, is there a way to check log messages when an app fails to launch? I already checked the console app, but there are no log messages when the app fails to launch.

Thank you.

Comment: You also need an `Info.plist` file in `Contents`

Comment: I already did. The p-list file works as the app launches when I click the executable (but not when I click the app folder)

Comment: There might be a problem with your Info.plist. How did you fill it?

Comment: When there's an error in the plist, the executable doesn't launch or throws an error. However, since the executable launches successfully, I don't think the problem is in the plist.

Comment: maybe a PATH problem in the script; make sure to use absolute PATHs or setting the PATH

Comment: The script seems to use AppPackageFolder = $(pwd) to get the path to the package folder. So I changed that line to AppPackageFolder = "absolute path to App.app" and the app still launches successfully when the exec file is clicked. However, my mac still says "cannot open app" when I click the app folder. Thank you so much for your help.